# export thermal loads from Abaqus

Tags: export, abaqus

I solve structural analysis and apply only temperature in nodes. I'd like to export global load vector from Abaqus. File inp looks like this:

```
**  Abaqus/fromAnsys 6.17-1
** 
**  reading Ansys data from: C:\temp\file1.cdb
**    creating Abaqus input: C:\temp\file1.inp
**   writing diagnostics to: C:\temp\file1.log
** 
**  Ansys Commands processed:
**       command   number
**  ------------   ------
**          ACEL        1
**        ANTYPE        1
**            BF        1
**         CGLOC        1
**       CGOMEGA        1
**        DCGOMG        1
**        DOMEGA        1
**        EBLOCK        1
**            ET        1
**         EQSLV        1
**        MPTEMP       13
**        MPDATA       13
**        NBLOCK        1
**         OMEGA        1
**          *SET       35
**          TIME        1
**  Ansys Commands NOT processed:
**       command   number
**  ------------   ------
**        ALPHAD        1
**         BETAD        1
**        BFUNIF        1
**        CRPLIM        2
**        DMPRAT        1
**           DOF        1
**         *ELSE        1
**        *ENDIF        1
**         ERESX        1
**        EXTOPT        3
**        FINISH        1
**           /GO        1
**           *IF        1
**          IRLF        1
**          KUSE        1
**             N        2
**          NCNV        1
**         NEQIT        1
**         /NOPR        1
**        NUMOFF        5
**        /PREP7        1
**       SECTYPE        1
**        /TITLE        1
**          TREF        1
** 
*Heading
** Job name: Job-1 Model name: file1
** Generated by: Abaqus/CAE 2017
*Preprint, echo=NO, model=NO, history=NO, contact=NO
**
** PARTS
**
*Part, name=PART-1
*Node
      1,           0.,           0.,           0.
      2,           1.,           0.,           0.
      3,           1.,           1.,           0.
      4,           0.,           1.,           0.
*Element, type=S4R
1, 1, 2, 3, 4
*Elset, elset=ES2_M1_E1_R1
 1,
** Section: Section-1-ES2_M1_E1_R1
*Shell Section, elset=ES2_M1_E1_R1, material=MATERIAL-1
0.0001, 3
*End Part
**  
**
** ASSEMBLY
**
*Assembly, name=Assembly
**  
*Instance, name=PART-1-1, part=PART-1
*End Instance
**  
*Nset, nset=Set-1, instance=PART-1-1, generate
 1,  4,  1
*End Assembly
** 
** MATERIALS
** 
**  ---------------------------------------------------
**  ---- *MATERIAL ------------------------------------
**  ---------------------------------------------------
** 
*Material, name=MATERIAL-1
*Elastic, type=ENGINEERING CONSTANTS
  1.039e+11, 9.62e+09, 9.62e+09,     0.25,     0.25,     0.33, 6.88e+09, 6.88e+09
 4.48e+09,      30.
 1.1039e+12, 9.62e+09, 9.62e+09,     0.25,     0.25,     0.33, 8.88e+09, 8.88e+09
 6.48e+09,      60.
*Expansion, type=ORTHO, zero=20.
 0.00016, 0.00016, 0.00015
** 
** PREDEFINED FIELDS
** 
** Name: Predefined Field-1   Type: Temperature
*Initial Conditions, type=TEMPERATURE
Set-1, 45.
```

I know, that it's necessary to add follow lines into the inp file for gravity force which defined in STEP. It's  only example.

The first part is used for export Global Stiffness Matrix.
The second part is used for export Global Load Vector.
But what about thermal loads in structural analysis?...
Thanks for your time.

```
** Output Global Stiffness Matrix
*Step, name=Global_Stiffness_Matrix
*MATRIX GENERATE, STIFFNESS
*MATRIX OUTPUT, STIFFNESS, FORMAT=COORDINATE
*End Step

*STEP
*MATRIX GENERATE,  STIFFNESS, LOAD
*MATRIX OUTPUT, STIFFNESS, LOAD, FORMAT=MATRIX INPUT
** 
** LOADS
** 
** Name: GRAVITY-1   Type: Gravity
*Dload
, GRAV, 10., 0., -1., 0.
*END STEP
```

Answer (score 0):

The load vector for the axial element has the contribution due to the springs and temperature in the form of

[image]

After incorporating the spring contribution into the stiffness matrix, you are left only with the thermo-mechanical load in the load vector. Thus, in the case of temperature load only, your load vector should contain thermal loads.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! But I have problems because I don't know what lines to add to the *.inp file to get the right side vector....